# How to create a private array?

Tags: powershell

To create a private variable we do `New-Variable strThree -Option Private`, where `strThree` is the name of the variable. But how do we create a private array?

Comment: Just use the `$private:` scope modifier when you declare your variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell is loosely typed. Just assign an array to the variable.

```
$varName = "privateArray"
New-Variable -Name $varName -Option Private
$privateArray = [string[]] @('asdf','asdf2','asdf3')

Write-host $privateArray.getType()
Write-Host $privateArray
```

results in:

> System.String[]
>
> asdf asdf2 asdf3